# Google Calendar API - Appropriate API Key Solution to Exceeded Quotas

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have a custom Windows service developed in C#.NET that synchronizes users' Google calendars with an internal calendar.

Per the Google Calendar API documentation, I'm using the below code. I believe this is referred to as the ClientLogin method which may or may not be advised (I've found conflicting information in the Google documentation).

```
CalendarService service = new CalendarService("Your app name");
service.setUserCredentials("username", "password");
```

This worked fine in testing. Now that things have moved to production, I'm receiving errors such as "The user has exceeded their quota, and cannot currently perform this operation" and "User has modified too many events today. Please try again tomorrow." This began more than a day ago and has remained as such.

I've researched this considerably and am still confused on a few points. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

1. What is the daily quota per user?
2. Are the (really low?) quotas there because an API key isn't being used by my application?
3. If I were to use an API key, which approach would I use for a Windows service in which I have the usernames and passwords for the Google users? - Simple API, OAuth2, Service Account, etc.

FYI: I am using the API .NET library provided by Google. If I should be using a particular authentication approach, I would appreciate a sample illustrating the implementation using the .NET library provided via Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you definitely don't use the latest version of the library. You can download it from NuGet. You should download the following two packages:

1. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/
2. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Authentication/ (be aware that in the next release we are going to improve the OAuth2 flows significantly, and support WP, Windows 8 application).

Regarding your questions:

1-2) Calendar API supports 100,000 requests/day. You can find that information in the Google API Console in the services tab.

3) Definitely OAuth2. Read more [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2).

You can find code samples with the current implementation of OAuth2 in our samples repository (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/?repo=samples)

Comment: Thank you very much for the information.  I have reviewed the OAuth2 flows and it seems all require that I direct the user to a Google URL to authorize the background service's access for their account.  Since the service will only access calendars for employees, is there a way that I can bypass this if I have the user credentials (secured in my own way)?  I understand the purpose of OAuth2 is the protect the user's credentials but it seems this must be a common scenario - accessing corporate email accounts for your own employees as simply as possible.

Comment: There is a specific OAuth2 scenario, "Password credentials grant" which enables you doing so  (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.3). But AFAIK, I'm not sure that Google server supports that.